# Trying to write a VR to prevent all but one role from updating a record to status of complete

Tags: validation, status

I suspect I'm making this harder on myself than I need to, but we have an object called "Portfolio__c", and there are several statuses available:  "Approval", "Received", "Sent Back", and "Completed".

I'm trying to prevent all but one role (and admin profiles) from being able to set the status to Completed.  All users should be able to change to any other status.

I'm just stumped - and would greatly appreciate any feedback or push in the right direction.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Have you tried to write this validation rule already? If so, please [edit] your question to include it. Showing us what you've done/tried/researched so far is a fundamental aspect of this site. It'd also be helpful to know how your validation rule is behaving (like "it works for case X, but case Y has an undesired result (details of result here)" ).

Comment: You can start with `$User.Role == 'Role Here' && Portfolio__c = 'Submitted'` Of portfolio is a picklist use ISPICKVAL

Answer (score 0):

AND($Profile.Name != 'System Administrator', $UserRole.Name != 'the role', TEXT(Status__c) == 'Completed')

Might it works